# Dynamodb Timestamp Range query with steps (It's possible??)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-streams

Well, my query is simple but I haven't seen (nor do I know if it exists) anything that does what I want.

I know how to make a Timestamp Query where I get a range of ordered data, the range would be from an initTimestamp to an endTimestamp.

However, I want to add a small complexity to the query (A filter??). Instead of returning ALL the items within that range, I want it to return items with a step/jump of X number of items.

That is, suppose that in that range I have `50` items, if I add a step of `10`, it should return the items: `[0, 9, 19, 29, 39, 49]`

I hope the question is understood.
I honestly don't know if it exists.

PS: I know that post-processing can be done, but the number of items is so enormous that a query of this style would be ideal.

Comment: No, this is not possible afaik.

Comment: my god... I have an extensive database table that is useless for certain cases, does that mean that I should create another table with more distant elements to be able to use that case? Will there be a solution for these cases without resorting to multiple calls to DynamoDB?

Comment: I haven't seen this 'step' capability in other databases but maybe I don't spend enough time in that space. Which databases provide arbitrary steps server-side through the result set?